# Arithmetic Overflow - Int32 MySQL to C#

Tags: c#, mysql, unix, overflow, type-conversion

## Architecture:

-A web server running windows 2008 with IIS 7 hosting a .NET Web application developed in .NET Framwork 4.0. On the same server i have driver MySQL ODBC 3.5.1 Driver

-A MySQL database server running on Unix

## Issue:

```
    public static List<Entity.Document> list(int companyId, int folderId, int userId)
    {
        //Initialise the results
        List<Entity.Document> results = new List<Entity.Document>();

        try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(string.Concat("SELECT id, name, parentfolderid, gid, companyid, is_deleted FROM tbl_document where parentfolderid = '" + folderId + "' and companyid = '", companyId, "' ORDER BY name"), connection))
                using (OdbcDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Entity.Document item = new Entity.Document();
                        
                        item.Id = int.Parse(dr["id"].ToString());
                        item.Name = dr["name"].ToString();
                        item.gId = Guid.Parse(dr["gid"].ToString());
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["parentfolderid"].ToString()))
                            item.FolderId = 0;
                        else
                            item.FolderId = int.Parse(dr["parentfolderid"].ToString());

                        if (dr["is_deleted"].ToString() == "1")
                            item.IsDeleted = true;
                        else
                            item.IsDeleted = false;

                        results.Add(item);
                    }
                    dr.Close();
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

When the line of code **item.Id = int.Parse(dr["id"].ToString());** is encountered, i have the following error that is being raised:

```
5/26/2015 (9:29 AM) - Method: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Entity.Folder] listFolders(Int32, Int32, Int32)
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetSqlType(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at DA.Folder.listFolders(Int32 parentFolderID, Int32 companyId, Int32 userId) in D:\Websites\AMS\AMS1.2\DA\Folder.cs:line 39
```

Note that i have also check the Type of the value that is being returned from dr["id"] and it is as follow:
Name: Int32

FullName: System.Int32

I have also tried System.Convert.ToInt32

You may find below a description of the targetted table:

```
mysql> describe tbl_folder;


+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name           | longtext   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parentfolderid | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| companyid      | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_deleted     | tinyint(4) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Any help will be much appreciated from you.

Comment: I also forgot to mention one important very point..it is working in development environment...windows pc hosting both iis and mysql db. Only when deploying on the mentioned architecture i am getting this issue

Comment: why don't you change this line `item.Id = int.Parse(dr["id"].ToString());` to the following 
`item.Id = int.Parse((int)dr["id"]);` since I am assuming that the datatype for the id field is being returned as an Integer..

Comment: You are selecting data from 'tbl_document' in your SQL query, not 'tbl_folder'. What is the type of the 'id' column in 'tbl_document'?

Comment: @Bernard Infact i am making two queries...one from tbl_folder and the other from tbl_document. I just happen to give the descrition of the other table. The type for id in tbl_document is int(6)

Comment: @MethodMan why would you `int.Parse` something you've casted to an int? Not sure that even compiles... It should be `item.Id = (int)dr["id"];` or even better, `item.Id = dr.GetInt32("id");`

Comment: @RonBeyer I meant to show my comment as a straight assignment I forgot to move the int.Parse section when doing my pasting / editing.. so you are correct `item.Id = (int)dr["id"]` since it's an auto incremented field the id field should never be null so what you have suggested will work.. good catch

Comment: @MethodMan if i'm not wrong, the int.Parse expects a string. Still the casting does not work. Compilation are in the order below: __The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments__ and __Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'__

Comment: @TheCoder you do not need the int.Parse in my opinion so you need to tell us when debugging.. what data value is of the id field once you execute the query in C# have you placed break points and inspected the data and variables ..?

Comment: so why not cast the string that you are trying to parse to an `(int)` like this 
`item.Id = (int)int.Parse(dr["id"].ToString());` which makes zero sense since you are trying to assign an integer value just do a direct assignment 
`item.Id = (int)dr["id"];` if you are totally confused then read up on the following here [C# MSDN int.Parse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also know the difference between casting and converting / implicit casting vs explicit casting

Comment: @MethodMan There is the break point ![Breakpoint](http://snag.gy/FUBdn.jpg).  This is from the development env of course. The same data and structure have been exported onto the Prod env

Comment: sorry @TheCoder I have no Idea what your're talking about.. your code is trying to parse a string as a parameter.. which can't convert integer to string error is probably what you're getting which is why I am asking why would you need to use the parse function when you know the datatype being returned is of type Int32..?

Comment: @MethodMan ok...you are right. I change it to the following `item.Id = (int)dr["id"];` since like u mention i know the type that is returned is int32. But i am still getting the same error message. :(

Comment: This is the results of the dumped sql statement:     +----+----------------+----------------+-----------+------------+
    | id | name           | parentfolderid | companyid | is_deleted |
    +----+----------------+----------------+-----------+------------+
    |  2 | SDDI           |              0 |         7 |          0 |
    |  7 | SDDI Transport |              0 |         7 |          0 |
    +----+----------------+----------------+-----------+------------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Another point that i've missed out is that my development env is on 32 bits (and it works fine there) and my prod env is on 64 bit. (with the same data but it doesnt work there!) Would that be having anything to do for the error?

Answer (score 1):

i manage to solve it. Deploying an app devloped on 32 bit OS on a 64 bit architecture was the issue. I compile the same source code on a 64 bit env and deployed it. It now works! Anyway thanks for your help :)